# Resolution and aspect ratio image sizes for bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my bootstrap carousel to take up the whole page of the user entering my site. However, with aspect ratios and resolution differences between monitors, I was wondering what is the best way to go about this?

I think I should first choose images of relatively the same size to start off. This is what I have so far.

css:

```
img {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

What if the images I am using have a super high resolution. Will this not fit on the user's page?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work , but I can't be sure .
but you can see it here :

http://jsfiddle.net/heyallanmoreno/7tdvu/4/

```
     <section class="block">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/750" alt="Slide1" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/750" alt="Slide2" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/750" alt="Slide3" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
 <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>

    </div>
</section>
```

and ,

```
.carousel .item {
    width: 100%; /*slider width*/
    max-height: 600px; /*slider height*/
}
.carousel .item img {
    width: 100%; /*img width*/
}
/*add some makeup*/
.carousel .carousel-control {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    top: 50%;
}
/*full width container*/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .block {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.